# Use shorter home screen app title so that it doesn't get truncated

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app

Change the `CFBundleDisplayName` to be something shorter so the app name is not truncated.

[image]

App version: 0.1.19

Comment: I kinda want to blame iOS 7 partly for this - some names that weren't truncated in iOS 6 now are in iOS 7. And yet some of the ones that don't, do when bold text is enabled.

Comment: And sometimes they do when the app is updated (the text is prepended with a • to indicate newness).

Comment: Wow iOS sucks with the title length there... Why even bother having titles if you only even get like 8-10 characters to use before it's truncated? But in all seriousness, how exactly would you suggest a simple title like "Stack Exchange" be shortened? "SE"? Because that would look even worse.

Comment: @AaronBrager I think the newly updated one is ok. It'll go away when you open the app for the first time.

Comment: Can't really blame iOS here, they use the same font across the OS, and this font does look pretty good. For the short name, I don't know if any of these would be suitable: "Stack Ex", "Stack X", "StackExchange".

Comment: I say just name it "Waffles" and be done with it.

Comment: It could just be called "Stack" (the name isn't taken).

Comment: @AaronBrager App display names are certainly not unique in iOS, so we can name it "Waffles" or "Stack".

Comment: There's planty of room there for "S.Exchange". Who could *possibly* have a problem with that? :P

Comment: Or StckXchng, as per Twttr

Comment: I vote for "Stack"

Comment: There *is* enough room for "Stack Exch" (I tried it by making a folder and renaming it that)

Comment: "Stack Exch" is my favourite of all the suggestions so far, followed closely by "SE".

Comment: Maybe "Xchg" instead of "Exch"?  I seem to recall vowels have lower entropy than consonants in English.  Or just "Stack Ex", the longest abbreviation consisting of complete syllables that fits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've discussed this before because we noticed the same thing.  We discussed several options, included several of the suggestions here, and ultimately decided that none of them were really better than "Stack Exc...".  One of the things we're trying to accomplish with the mobile apps is to increase awareness of the entire Stack Exchange network.  Certainly, inside-joke names might appeal to the denizens of Meta, but wouldn't do anything to accomplish that goal.  Abbreviations or shorthand like "Stack" or SE are better, but don't *really* improve on what we have now in terms of promoting our overall brand.

**Update:** 
I tried removing the space to see if it would help, and it doesn't:

[image]

Comment: You raise a good point about awareness. I'd counter that "Stack Exch" is in fact longer and more legible/explicit than the "Stack Exc" that currently exists. For comparison, I would also like to point out that *very* few apps have a name too long to fit (I only found two on my phone), and those that do tend to be by smaller developers who aren't aware.

Comment: Even "Stack Exc." would look better than "Stack Exc..." looks more like a deliberate choice rather than an oversite

Comment: What about changing to "StackExchange"? Good chance it will cause the whole name to show up.

Comment: Weird, I got my share of apps and SE's is the only one getting truncated even though others have same length or even longer names.

Comment: StackEx is catchy, short, and clear.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are multiple places you can give the app a name. In the App Store it can be the full Stack Exchange, and then something shorter on the home screen

Comment: Regarding your update: "StackExch" somehow seems better to me than "StackExc".  Or perhaps it's just me.

Answer (score 12):

I don't get it.

I also have SO Web App added to home screen which shows the full "StackOverflow" app title.

However, the SE native app shows only "Stack Exc..."

[image]

Both have the same number of characters. However, I do notice that there is no space between "Stack" and "Overflow". Does this have anything to do with the title truncation?

I am on iOS 7.1.1, if that makes any difference.

Comment: In iOS 7, apparently web apps can break this rule. I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour or Apple's bug. I also use Test Flight web app and it does this too.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried making a web app called Stack Exchange and got the same truncation as the app gets

Comment: It seems not the number of characters that matters, it's the width in pixels. 'Exc' is about the same width as 'Ove', but r f and l are narrower (in that font) than h and a. Looks like some kerning is in effect there also ('ve' and 'ow'). I think StackOverflow would be ellipsized too if it were just a pixel or two wider.

Comment: Hmmm.... Proportionate? I tried with space between "stack" and "overflow" and still the complete display. In case of SE, even if the space is removed it still gets truncated. Strange. It seems @deltab's logic makes sense here.